# ZvP How to deal with a Pylon-blocked natural?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

As a Bronze Zerg, I find that whenever my natural is blocked/cannon rushed by a Protoss opponent that by the time that I've dealt with it I'm a long way behind. Then subsequent 2-base pressure is the coup de grace.

In my last ZvP game, I went 14 pool with the aim of going 15 hatch. When the Pylon blocked my Natural, I pulled 2 drones, whilst I waited for my Pool to pop, to kill the Probe and attack the Pylon. A cannon was placed before I managed to kill the Probe, so I pulled a further 2 Drones, so that I now had 4 Drones attacking the cannon. The cannon was cancelled at the very last minute, so for very little cost and effort from the Protoss' behalf, I've now lost a considerable amount of mining time. I eventually cleaned up the Pylon and took my Natural and droned-up like crazy, but around the 11 minute mark, when the Warp gate pressure came I didn't have enough to hold it off.

What's the correct way to deal with this sort of strategy? Is there any way to punish a Protoss that just goes FFE behind this?

Thanks

Comment: If a protos canon rushes in your natural that probably means he has no (almost none) defences in his main. Otherwise it was no rushing. Just counterattack him with 3 pair of zerglings and punish him by killing every probe.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64968/how-to-combat-protoss-walling-in-a-zergs-base?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to go with a macro heavy build, then you basically play against yourself. This might differ if you go higher in the leagues.

Here is how to deal with a blocked Natural:

Your main strategy is go 3 base into whatever you want. To figure out if you opponent is going all-in or expanding with scouting. If you know this is no all-in then you are safe to take your 3rd (even though this is your 2nd base). With 2-4 Zerglings you can easily destroy the pylon and build another base at your natural (this will be your 3rd base). After this it is just a standard 3 base strategy play.

Further information:

Search for a 3 base strategy that you personally like and learn the BO and the timings by heart. You can open a single player game and optimize your build. Just imagine the opponent placed a pylon at your natural, so expand there later. If you do not do this you might crumble under the pressure you opponent applies with harassment.

The investment of the Protoss is too small to be punishable. Think of it as a slight variation where your goal is to adapt your build so you do not fall behind or get a slight edge over your opponent. He invests 100 minerals to force you into 1 base all-in or 3 base play. Still the 3 base play is a very solid opening, you just have to know how to execute it.

Comment: Like ayckoster says. 1: Take the nearest expo. for your 2nd. or 2: All in on short maps.

Comment: Whilst I was watching [HappyZerg](http://www.teamliquid.net/tlpd/sc2-international/players/1581_HappyZerG) stream today, he encountered the same problem/strategy and reacted in a similar fashion to what you suggested - using 4 lings to kill the pylon and taking a quick 3rd. I guess it's time to learn some new strategies and adapt.

Answer (score 1):

I would say more important than learning a strategy is learning the game. Realize that Starcraft is a game of math. If you have more stuff than your opponent, you win. The way you have more stuff is more bases.As a Zerg, you should always ask yourself a simple question, "Am I safe?" If you are, make drones, if you aren't, make units.

Concerning the pylon block and why you should fast expand to three bases is simple. Your opponent has invested in a forge, a pylon, and a cannon. This amounts to 150+150+100=400 minerals. This is the same as a nexus. Or almost 3 gateways. Therefore, he can't have those as well, can he? And if he can, then he certainly doesn't have units. He's just as behind as you are, if not more. So you should be able to realize he can't attack you. He can't attack you = free base. And as Zerg, you should ALWAYS be looking for a free base.

I hope this has helped you to better think about the game. While imitation of a build order is important for improving macro ability, being able to understand the game is better for telling you how to react. GL HF!